# process array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I have this code,

```
"data": [
    {
        "pid": 1,
        "status": "done",
        "title": "a"
    },
    {
        "pid": 1,
        "status": "pending",
        "title": "a"
    },
    {
        "pid": 1,
        "status": "pending",
        "title": "21"
    },
    {
        "pid": 2,
        "status": "pending",
        "title": "c"
    }
]
```

I am trying to process it like this

```
"data": [
    {
        "pid": 1,
        "done": 1,
        "pending":2
    },
    {
        "pid": 2,
        "done": 0,
        "pending":1
    }
]
```

I have tried much to produce my desired results but no luck, now i m posting here to get some help.

thanks

Comment: What is the logic behind the expected result? For future reference please read through the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: as I have mentioned @Andreas i want to achieve above results. in PHP i know the logic and code but in node.js i m unable to achieve same

Comment: @palaѕн i have included a sample code this is not the same at my side , out come result is also sample original code is bit lengthy, by@Terry's hint of Array.reduce is fine. sometimes we nly need a hint .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) for this purpose.

We create a map, keyed by pid then add 1 for each done or pending object.
[Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) will then turn this map into an array again.
I hope this helps you!

```js
data = [
    {
        "pid": 1,
        "status": "done",
        "title": "a"
    },
    {
        "pid": 1,
        "status": "pending",
        "title": "a"
    },
    {
        "pid": 1,
        "status": "pending",
        "title": "21"
    },
    {
        "pid": 2,
        "status": "pending",
        "title": "c"
    }
]

let result = Object.values(data.reduce( (map, d) => {
    if (!map[d.pid]) map[d.pid] = { pid: d.pid, done: 0, pending: 0 };
    if (d.status === "done") map[d.pid].done++;
    if (d.status === "pending") map[d.pid].pending++;
    return map;
}, {} ));

console.log("Result:", result);
```

Comment: Hey, @Shahbaz, is it an old version of Node.js? If you can give me the node version, I'll change the code to be compatible. It's probably just Object.values that is the issue, in which case it's easy to work around. This should be present from Node.js 7.0.0 and later.

Comment: thanks @Terry its working now there was another bug due to which it arise, i will mark your answer accepted, much appreciated for ur hint on Array.reduce. thanks man

Comment: No problen @Shahbaz, very glad to help! Array.reduce is very powerful and flexible!